# Programatically switch user's selection to "dashed line" type selection in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want a user to select a cell range, but do the selection not in the regular selection mode with solid lines, but the dashed line mode like when the user is selecting cells in a function like `SUM()`. This way, the original cell that they are on still retains its selected state.

Is there a way to switch to this type of secondary selection mode in VBA? (Not sure if there's a proper term for this.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing? If you have some code, you can ask the user to select a range with `Input type:=8`...what do you mean by "...the original cell that they are on still retains its selected state."

Comment: I have a non-VBA application that runs inside Excel, which can call VBA procedures. At some point, the user will be asked to select a cell range. I want any selection that they make to be in this kind of range selection mode, without needing to pop up some other prompt.

Comment: So `varInput = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range:", Type:=8)` does what I want, but I don't want to open a prompt.

Comment: What will trigger this selection? (how will your app ask the user?)

Comment: It will be triggered by a button press, but any instructions or text box showing the selected range will be within the app.

Comment: @xli Then put a text box in sheet where user will input their range and a button which will select that range.

Comment: @harun24hr The button will be in the outside application, not in the sheet though.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
if button_pressed = true then
    Selection.Copy
End if
button_pressed = false
End Sub
```